# if Statement Condition for powerpoint add on

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, powerpoint, add-on

I am using the ''_SlideShowNextSlide(PowerPoint.SlideShowWindow Wn)" event for making a powerpoint add on in visual studio in C# and I need the condition for an if statement for if the user has ended the slideshow or pressed ESC.

Also if I there I could get the condition for if the user has pressed down or gone to the next slide that would be great too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing down (arrow or page, either one) would go to the next slide, as would going to the next slide, and in either case, the NextSlide event you mention would be triggered.

For end show, there's an Application.SlideShowEnd event.  Or for an If test, you could test whether Application.SlideShowWindows.Count is 0.  If so, no slide show.